# compute: $\int_{0}^{1}e^x(1-x)^{100}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to compute: $\int_{0}^{1}e^x(1-x)^{100}dx$. I tried to use integration by parts but it didn't work out for me(since I need to do that 100 times, and obviously there's a shorter solution) ,  I substituted  $(1-x)=u$ and got $e\int_0^1e^{-t}t^{100}$, again I can't do with that much. Any suggestion how should solve this integral?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Try for a [Reduction Formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae) For that, Parts is (are?) good.

Comment: Please expand on "it didn't work out for me"? Which result did you get -- in which way did that not work out?

Comment: I imagine the easiest thing to do is expand $e^{-t}t^{100}$ into a power series.

Comment: Just as a side note: If all you want to do is **estimate** the integral, there's a nifty trick: $\int_0^1 e^x (1-x)^{100} \approx \int_0^1 e^x e^{-100x} \approx \int_0^{\infty} e^{-99x}=\frac{1}{99}$ that gets you within about 1% of the correct answer.

Comment: My answer below is exact and in closed form, if you allow the floor function.

Comment: You may write $(1-x)^{100}$ as $(x-1)^{100}$ and use Tabular Integration (which is just slightly more organised by Parts).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For what it's worth:

Write
$$
t^{100}e^{-t}=t^{100}(1-t+{t^2\over 2!}-{t^3\over 3!}-\cdots )
=t^{100}-t^{101}+{t^{102}\over 2!}-{t^{103}\over 3!}-\cdots
$$

The above series is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$; thus:
$$
\eqalign{
\int_0^1 e^{-t}t^{100}\,dt
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 (-1)^n{t^{100+n}\over n!}\cr

&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty   (-1)^n{t^{101+n}\over({101+n}) n!}\Bigl|_0^1\cr
 
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty   (-1)^n{1\over({101+n}) n!}. \cr
}
$$

Comment: Worth a lot. very nice, Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The integral is exactly the fractional part of $100!\,e$, or in other words $100!\ e-\lfloor100!\ e\rfloor\approx0.00999901019\ldots$

Apply integration by parts to the integral $I_n=\int_0^1e^{1-t}t^n\,dt$ (it's nicer *not* to pull the $e$ out to the front) and we find for $n\geq1$, $$I_n=-1+nI_{n-1}$$

This gives us $$I_{100}=-1+100[-1+99[-1+98[-1+\cdots+2[-1+1I_0]\cdots]]]$$

$I_0$ is a straightforward computation: $e-1$. So

This gives us $$I_{100}=-1+100[-1+99[-1+98[-1+\cdots+2[-1+e-1]\cdots]]]$$

Here is a nice observation. Once this is multiplied out, it (clearly?) simplifies to $100!\,e-N$ for some *integer* $N$. A graphical examination of the integral reveals that $I_{100}$ is somewhere between $0$ and $1$. (You could prove this using the fact that $e^{1-t}t^{100}=e^{1-t}tt^{99}\leq t^{99}$ on $[0,1]$.) So $N$ must equal the integer part of $100!\,e$, leaving $I_{100}$ to be the fractional part.

---

It's interesting to note that since $I_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, the fractional part of $n!\,e$ must approach zero; that is, $n!\,e$ gets closer and closer to being an integer. (Although I suppose that is obvious if we consider the usual series expansion for $e$.)

---

For computational purposes, we can use this to find a decimal approximation by throwing out the first $100$ terms or so (which are all integers) of the series expansion for $100!\, e$.

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1e^{1-t}t^{100}\,dt & 
= 100!\, e-\lfloor100!\,e\rfloor\\
& = \sum_{n=101}^{\infty}\frac{100!}{n!}
\end{align}
$$

This is the series that bgins has found with a slightly different argument. At first, this series converges faster than David Mitra's alternating series. It is correct to at least 17 decimal places after only 8 partial summands. David's requires 18 partial summands to get that much accuracy. However since both series have a ratio of order $1/n$ and David's series is alternating, I think that in the long run for very high accuracy demands, his series might be better.

Comment: Very good answer!

Answer (score 4):

Use the formula 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^x\ \sum_{n\ge0}\ (-1)^n\ f^{(n)}(x)\right)=e^x\ f(x),
$$
which holds if $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @WillieWong Is it even true that this series $\sum (-1)^nf^{(n)}(x)$ necessarily converges for all real analytic functions?  If it converges, then for any $x$, $\sum (-1)^nf^{(n)}(x)/n!$ converges, so that means the Taylor series around $x$ must have radius of convergence $\geq 1$. But we can easily construct real analytic functions that don't have radius of convergence $1$ at some $x$, can't we?  Like $\frac{1}{1+4x^2}$, which has a radius of convergence $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Oops. @Thomas and Pierre-Yeves, I was too hasty at computing the decay condition needed. Deleting my previous comment. What I was trying to say is that "which holds if $f$ is a polynomial" can be replaced by a suitable convergence condition, and that the sum doesn't really have to terminate. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use integration by parts. You will end up with a recursion, like this:

$$\int\limits_0^1 {{e^{ - x}}{x^n}dx = \left[ { - {e^{ - x}}{x^n}} \right]_0^1}  + n\int\limits_0^1 {{e^{ - x}}} {x^{n - 1}}dx$$
$${I_n} =   -\frac{1}{e} + n{I_{n - 1}}$$

where

$$\int\limits_0^1 {{e^{ - t}}{t^n}dt}  = {I_n}$$

Using it sufficient times you'll end up with your result.

Comment: Thanks! sadly solving this exercise  it's not up my choice :)

Comment: *You should use integration by parts*... Actually this is not necessary. // Unless I am mistaken, the value of $I_n$ that you propose is negative, you might want to modify this.

Comment: @DidierPiau I used $$\int\limits_0^1 {{e^{ - x}}{x^n}dx = \left[ { - {e^{ - x}}{x^n}} \right]_0^1}  + \int\limits_0^1 {{e^{ - x}}n} {x^{n - 1}}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $1-x = t$ , so :

$I= -e \int \limits_1^0 e^{-t} \cdot t^{100}\,dt =e \int \limits_0^1 e^{-t} \cdot t^{100}\,dt$

Now substitute : $-t=s$ , so :

$I= -e \int \limits_0^{-1} e^{s} \cdot s^{100}\,ds = e \int \limits_{-1}^{0} e^{s} \cdot s^{100}\,ds$

This integral you can solve using Integration by parts several times .For start choose :

$u = s^{100}~$ , and $dv = e^s ds$

Answer (score 2):

As already said, this is $I_n$ for $n=100$, where
$$
I_n=\int_0^1x^n\mathrm e^{1-x}\mathrm dx.
$$
To compute $I_n$ for every $n\geqslant0$ at once, one can group these in a series, that is, consider, for every $s$ small enough,
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{s^n}{n!}I_n=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{s^n}{n!}x^n\mathrm e^{1-x}\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\mathrm e^{1-x(1-s)}\mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm e-\mathrm e^{s}}{1-s}.
$$
The expansion of the first part of the RHS is 
$$
\frac{\mathrm e}{1-s}=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}\mathrm es^n.
$$
As regards the second part, one knows that
$$
\mathrm e^s\cdot\frac1{1-s}=\left(\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}\frac{s^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}s^n\right),
$$
whose coefficient of $s^n$ is
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}.
$$
Putting all these together yields
$$
\frac{I_n}{n!}=\mathrm e-\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac1{k!}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant n+1}\frac1{k!},
$$
and finally,
$$
I_n=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}\frac{n!}{(n+k)!},
$$
To get an approximate value of $I_n$, one can proceed as follows. Keeping only the first term of the series in the RHS yields a lower bound. Replacing the $k$th term by $\frac1{(n+1)^k}$ and summing the resulting series yields an upper bound. These read
$$
\frac1{n+1}\lt I_n\lt\frac1n.
$$

Comment: And more generally, 
$$ \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \ldots
+ \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+k)} < I_n < 
\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \ldots
+ \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+k-1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+k-2)(n+k-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

With $t=1-x,~dt=-dx$, the integral
$$
I=\int_{0}^{1}e^x(1-x)^{100}dx=e\int_{0}^{1}t^{100}e^{-t}dt=e\;I_{100}
$$
can be expressed in terms of
$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}e^{-t}dt$.
Using integration by parts
with $u=t^n,~du=nt^{n-1}dt$
and $v=-e^{-t},~dv=e^{-t}dt$,
we find for $n>0$
$$
I_n
=\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}e^{-t}dt
=\left[-t^ne^{-t}\right]_0^1
+n\int_{0}^{1}t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt
=-\frac1e+nI_{n-1}
$$
while $I_0=1-\frac1e$,
since at the lower endpoint,
$t^0=1$ does not vanish.
Unraveling the recursion,
we find
$$
I_n=n!\left(1-\frac1e\;\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\right)
=\frac{n!}{e}\left(e-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{n!}{e}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k!}
%=\frac1e\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{n!}{k!}% (hidden) extra step!
=\frac1e\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}
$$
which can be bounded thus:
$$
\frac{e^{-1}}{n+1}
<I_n
<\frac1e\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k}
=\frac{e^{-1}}{n-1}
$$
In particular,
$$
I=e\;I_{100}
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{100!}{(100+k)!}
=\frac1{101}
+\frac1{101\cdot102}
+\frac1{101\cdot102\cdot103}
+\cdots
$$
Numerically, this agrees with David Mitra's more elegant solution,

$$
\eqalign{
I_n
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {(-1)^k\over k!} \int_0^1 t^{n+k} dt \cr
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {(-1)^k\over (n+k+1)k!}. \cr
}
$$
I offer only some numerical evidence of this from Sage
(which used maxima for at least the third quantity).

```
x=var('x')
I=integral(e^x*(1-x)^100,x,0,1)
I.n(digits=400)
```

> 0.009999010191094737330783479071750558784854694330\
>   66671978145864533161714326816356034370681432918468\
>   53285140817781582051413229186884063403403557977080\
>   02120596655485207781703353097131323526778542109794\
>   17015925291075182530361953938643022940937197666661\
>   05165157555781181237126456446981437647360344459677\
>   36642319892827301897254303584248930056503030250811\
>   27060937927312963829104793337147051891405375697835

```
k = var('k')
I1 = sum(factorial(100)/factorial(100+k), k, 1, infinity)
I1.n(digits=396) # sum of positive terms
```

> 0.009999010191094737330783479071750558784854694330\
>   66671978145864533161714326816356034370681432918468\
>   53285140817781582051413229186884063403403557977080\
>   02120596655485207781703353097131323526778542109794\
>   17015925291075182530361953938643022940937197666661\
>   05165157555781181237126456446981437647360344459677\
>   36642319892827301897254303584248930056503030250811\
>   27060937927312963829104793337147051891405375697835

```
# sum is to 1000 because summing to infinity took too long
I2=e*sum((-1)^k/factorial(k)/(k+101), k, 0, 1000); I2.n(digits=396)
I2.n(digits=396) # alternating series
```

> 0.009999010191094737330783479071750558784854694330\
>   66671978145864533161714326816356034370681432918468\
>   53285140817781582051413229186884063403403557977080\
>   02120596655485207781703353097131323526778542109794\
>   17015925291075182530361953938643022940938823909717\
>   30629190237480312082277049371942004495735825187534\
>   58710947176445868284110586963289380133420798065473\
>   61761071441791460666209221052877877060247573885386

We can see that the third quantity,
the more elegantly derived alternating series,
as it was calculated above, differs from the
first two (as they were calculated)
by about $0.17\times10^{-238}$,
i.e., its fifth row ends with
$8823909717$ rather than $7197666661$.

Comment: Shouldn't $(e-1)100!\sum_{k=0}^{100}\frac1{k!}\approx e(e-1)\cdot 100!$?

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$ I_n = e\int_0^1 e^{-t} t^n dt $$

We have (integration by part) $I_n=n I_{n-1} - 1$, and $I_0 = e-1$.

Write $I_n$ as $a_n e - b_n$, with $a_n$ and $b_n$ rational numbers.
We have $a_n = n a_{n-1}$ and $b_n = n b_{n-1} +1$, with $a_0=1=b_0=1$.

So obviously, $a_n = n!$.
Way less obviously, we have $b_n = A000522(n)$. See the [OIES][1](http://oeis.org/A000522) page for generating series and other forms for $b_n$.
The recurrence in itself is a very nice form, it allows the use of fast algorithms to compute a lot of terms. It also allows for asymptotic analysis.

So in the end,
$$ e\int_0^1 e^{-t} t^n dt = n! e - A000522(n)  $$

Computer easily find that $b_{100} = A000522(100)$ is 2536869555601272974152707482122802204451475785662981422327751859874492\
5390838644651894048542515204979326740773232800349360951349984969417670\
9764490323163992001

Bonus : the factorization of $b_{100}$ :

`{{59, 1}, {197, 1}, {281, 1}, {617, 1}, {6791290111, 
  1}, {29565843698156503, 1}, {42933474506607537350507, 
  1}, {146032600411218505211021315344688241113203163378586255678583083\
99982138258246286181319177385766944701, 1}}`

Answer (score 1):

For $n>-1$, consider $$I=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\rm d}t\,e^{t}(1-t)^{n}.$$ With the substitution $u=1-t$ $$I=e \int\limits_{0}^{1}{\rm d}u{\hspace{1pt}} e^{-u}u^{n}=e \Bigg(\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{\rm d}u{\hspace{1pt}} e^{-u}u^{n}-\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}{\rm d}u{\hspace{1pt}} e^{-u}u^{n}\Bigg)=e\big[\Gamma(n+1)-\Gamma(n+1,1)\big],$$ where $\Gamma(s)$ and $\Gamma(s,a)$ are the gamma and incomplete gamma functions respectively. For $n=100$ we have $e\big[\Gamma(101)-\Gamma(101,1)\big]\approx 0.009999$.

Comment: If $u=1-x$ then how does $e^t$ become $e^{-u}$?  Could you have intended $e^x$ and $dx$ where you wrote $e^t$ and $dt$?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed it.

Comment: This is also explained following http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5Ek%2Fexp(x) - nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^1e^x(1-x)^{100}~dx$

$=\int_1^0e^{1-x}x^{100}~d(1-x)$

$=\int_0^1x^{100}e^{1-x}~dx$

$=-\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^{100}\dfrac{100!x^ne^{1-x}}{n!}\right]_0^1$ (can be obtained from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_of_polynomials)

$=100!e-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{100}\dfrac{100!}{n!}$